# How to find COM object given only server.create instance?

Tags: com, asp-classic

I have inherited a classic ASP application and looking through the code I see a custom COM object reference

```
Server.CreateObject("DBaseManager.Recordset")
```

Now, unfortunately looking through to source code there are no .dlls provided so therefore the COM dll *must* still exist on the live server.

In order to get the code working on my Dev Server I need to get a copy of the dll so I can register it on my Dev server.

Does anyone have any recommendations about how I might be able to find the COM dll that makes the above call?

Thanks and best wishes
Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Registry search - under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, locate the `DBaseManager.Recordset` key. Under that key, there should be a `CLSID` key, with a default value containing a guid.

Now, search for that guid under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID`. There should be a subkey under that key called `InprocServer32` (if it's an in-process COM library), which in turn should have a default value giving the path to the DLL.

---

Of course, if the DLL in question is part of a larger product or SDK, merely installing the dll on your dev server may not be sufficient. You may have to locate and install the whole product/SDK in order for it to actually work on another machine.

Comment: +1. And that script could be helpful too : http://support.softartisans.com/kbview_1294.aspx